# Pandas - Identifying date of switch in a multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-cleaning, multi-index

I have a very large dataframe that is multiindexed as `('ID','Date')`; the column `'Value'` tracks an individual's progress in time using a boolean.

I know that each individual starts and ends with Value = True. I've been able to locate the date for the first occurrence of False using `df.loc[~df['Value'], :]`, but what I want to be able to do is locate the date when they switched back to True after one or more periods of False. I've tried using variations on `.groupby().diff()` but this is extremely slow.

Example: I want to extract "7-22-19" for individual A, below:

**ID**---**Date**------Value

A----1-30-19---True

A----3-15-19---False

A----4-1-19-----False

A----7-22-19---True

A----11-13-19--True

B----2-1-19-----True

etc.

As an extra caveat, a solution that is both fast (my dataframe has hundreds of thousands of IDs so no loops, and `.groupby().diff()` seems to be slow) and that works with non-booleans would be ideal (i.e. if we replace True/False with Drug X/Drug Y).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift` is a nice tool to detect transitions in a column. So you could find transitions from False to True for the same ID with:

```
df.loc[df['Value']&((~df['Value']).shift())&(df['ID']==df['ID'].shift())]
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
  ID     Date  Value
3  A  7-22-19   True
```